# Spring boot - Thymeleaf vs. JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to **JQuery**, and so far I used it in side projects to add visual animations to the user interface. Since I always used **Thymeleaf** on the UI when writing a **Spring Boot application**, I was satisfied combining the two of them. The data from the user side goes through the **Model** via Thymeleaf, which is processed by the server, and then it injects the results in different objects back to the UI (via the Model again).

But now I started to simplify the process by using JQuery ajax queries, which have the benefit of getting rid of page refreshing, and also I don't have to use the model to inject the objects into every single page. *(In case of Thymeleaf, even if a user decides not to change something on the page - like a form - an object still needs to be there - just in case - which will store their changes.)*

The question is: **Is that a good strategy to get rid of the Thymeleaf and using pure HTML+JQuery to do all the request+response work on the userinterface?** I was wondering **if there is any cons of it**, as there are many people using thymeleaf to handle these stuff without JS, and maybe they have a good reason to do that way.

Comment: You can refresh fragments on the site, with this you prevent the whole page reload. I think the following is what you looking for: http://xpadro.blogspot.de/2014/02/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-2.html

Comment: Thank you Manu, but in that example they are also using JQuery to triggering the refresh, mixing it with the model. My question is more like, if it is a good strategy to use JQuery and eliminating Thymeleaf/Models.

Comment: Properly will be DID NOT mess javascript and HTML. If you will use this approach, you will have no problems with any template engine and any js framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So after all I think I have found an answer for the question, by considering some important aspects just like:**

## **Code Reusability**

A big benefit of using a framework like Thymeleaf is that you can easily reuse the code what you have written - in case of TL - by using fragments. Creating the front-end in pure HTML+JQuery means every single page needs to have a separate .html, except if we build a single page application, but in that case using Angular would be much more efficient.

## **Security**

Another aspect which I didn't take into consideration; Thymeleaf is compatible with Spring Security, also it has it's specific syntax which is hidden from the user at runtime. If a server is REST server (as it is in several cases when working with Spring boot) additional security needs to be implemented, what Thymeleaf can help with. (Additional security is mostly needed anyway)

So probably the best solution is to stay with Thymeleaf, using JQuery as a support on the interface (just like caching the data when using ajax, which Thymeleaf is not that good at, and also doing the visual bells and whistles) and let them work together.